# How to get a function name using a parent name?

Tags: javascript

If I have object called menu:

```
var menu  ={
    pizza: getMenu,    
    burger: getMenu
}

function getMenu(){
    //do something
}
```

I want if I call `menu.burger()` to `console.log` 'burger'  and doing `menu.pizza()` to log 'pizza'.

I do not want to pass any parameter to the `getMenu` and calling `arguments.callee.name` will always return `getMenu`. Is there another way to get the name calling the `getMenu` function?

Comment: What you're trying to do is not possible without changing `menu` in a way that it no longer represents a ordinary object.

Comment: Can you elaborate more?  And lets say pizza and burger are hard coded they wont change in menu , can we then find the names?(calling menu.pizza() will give me 'pizza')

Comment: Short answer: JavaScript doesn't have a concept of "caller names" like you're looking for.

Comment: thank you for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution, fine but not beautiful :D

```
var menu = {
  pizza: getMenu,
  burger: getMenu
}

function getMenu() { console.log('do something') }


Object.keys(menu).forEach(item => {
  Object.defineProperty(menu, item, {
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    set(val){
      this.value=val
    },
    get() {
      console.log(item)
      return this.value
    }
  })
  menu[item] = getMenu
})


console.log(menu.pizza())
```

Comment: I think your close but the object.keys(menu) should be inside the getMenu function.  I will try to use this approach.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of achieving what you want. Either by using a non-enumerable tracker on the menu object, or modifying the functions a bit. I'll write here the simplest one:

```
var menu  ={
    pizza: function(){getMenu.call(this,"pizza")},    
    burger: function(){getMenu.call(this,"burger")}
}

function getMenu(key){
    console.log(key);
}
menu.pizza();//pizza
```

If you want to achieve what you want without passing a parameter to getMenu, you would need to use another nonenumerable getter/setter to keep track of the last called method. Other ways can also achieve that, but if all you want is to console log, I'd use anonymous functions that are kept separately in memory so they are unique:

```
   var menu  ={
        pizza: function(){for(var i in this){if(this[i] === menu.pizza){console.log(i);break;}}},    
        burger: function(){for(var i in this){if(this[i] === menu.burger){console.log(i);break;}}}
    }
    menu.pizza()//pizza
```

wayyy simpler

Comment: As the OP stated: _"I do not want to pass any parameter to the `getMenu`"_

Comment: yeah i cannot pass any parameters. I know its something harder but it is a challenge i need to make.

Comment: if you are not doing something complicated later on with these, just use anonymous functions. I updated the answer a bit.

Comment: Yeah however this was a challenge the conditions are exactly as i wrote my code above. The only change i can make in inside the getMenu() function.(without passing parameter to getMenu).
But the code you gave me can be tweaked i guess so ill try to test and see what I can do. Thank you as well for your help and reply.